# Issue with error handling, error does not seem to be recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Hello there the problem is that when I try to run a try expect block in python, it seems to not catch my errors.

The code catches an error but it doesn't catch the error that I have set, I have tried if else statements to catch the error and now try catches but it seems like its just not being passed into those blocks.

```
import sys

INVALID_NUM_ARGS_ERROR = "At least two arguments not provided"
INVALID_NUM_ERROR = "Invalid number provided"

def your_main_program(args):
    # Call your methods from here, using the
    # relevant items in args

    num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
    num2 = int(sys.argv[2])

    try:
        if len(sys.argv) == 3:
            multiply(num1, num2)

        elif len(sys.argv) == 4:
            if(num1 or num2 == 0):
                raise_string(num1, num2)

            formula = ''
            formula += (str(num1) + ' * ') * (num2 - 1)
            formula += str(num1)
            print(formula)
            raise_string(num1, num2)

    except ValueError:
        print(INVALID_NUM_ERROR)
```

I expect the output of `[Invalid number provided]`, but the actual output turns out to be `[Traceback (most recent call last):]`

**Raise String Code**

```
def raise_string(num1, num2):
    "Prints our the two numbers to the power of itself"
    answer = num1**num2
    print(answer)
    return answer
```

**Traceback***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script1.py", line 50, in <module>
    your_main_program(sys.argv)
  File "script1.py", line 15, in your_main_program
    num2 = int(sys.argv[2])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'calls
```

Comment: This means that somewhere in your code, something other than a `ValueError` is being raised. Can you share the complete text of the Traceback?

Comment: Can you add the code of `raise_string`

Comment: Also add sample function  calls to `your_main_program`

Comment: The call to `int()` that is failing, as clearly indicated in the traceback, *isn't inside your try-except*.

Comment: I can't believe i did not notice that..god I dislike programming at times haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code may be look like this:

```
import sys

INVALID_NUM_ARGS_ERROR = "At least two arguments not provided"
INVALID_NUM_ERROR = "Invalid number provided"


def your_main_program(args):
    # Call your methods from here, using the
    # relevant items in args

    try:
        num1 = int(args[1])
        num2 = int(args[2])
    except ValueError:
        print(INVALID_NUM_ERROR)

    length = len(args)
    if length == 3:
        multiply(num1, num2)
    elif length == 4:
        if num1 == 0 or num2 == 0:
            raise_string(num1, num2)
        else:
            formula = " * ".join([str(num1)] * num2)
            print(formula)
            raise_string(num1, num2)


def multiply(n1, n2):
    print(f"{n1} * {n2} = {n1*n2}")


def raise_string(n1, n2):
    print(f"{n1} ** {n2} = {n1**n2}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    your_main_program(sys.argv)
```